# Is the .class file deleted after the client sends request for a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I try to understand the JSP and Servlets and I have found this statement in a tutorial: The .class file of Servlet is executed by the JSP container and the output of execution is sent to client as response. If the same JSP file is not used again, the .class file is deleted. If used again and often, the .class file is retained by the container for further usage without the need of second time translation and compilation. This is to increase the performance.

I don't understand when exactly the .class file is deleted?

For example if a web client sends request to Web server for a JSP page today, and after one month another web client sends a request to web server for the same JSP page. Is the .class file deleted or not after the first request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is called a cache (caching the file) and it really depends.  If the web server does not need the space used by the `.class` file it may keep it for a loooong time.  So, it depends on how frequent is the web server used, how much space/memory it was allocated to work with and how large the JSPs are (and the resulting `.class` files), as well as how many other Java objects (and their size) it also has to keep track of.  In some web containers you can also specify how long to cache these files for and to force a new compile if the file is older than a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for reply!